# MySQL Server 5.6 won't start on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, centos, centos7

I have a 512MB VPS at DigitalOcean running latest CentOS 7. MySQL 5.6 was installed using these commands:

```
yum localinstall http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql-community-server
```

And I am using the following for my **my.cnf**:

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = MyISAM
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 128M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 100
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 100

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 0
slow-query-log                 = 0
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

When I tried to start MySQL using these command variation, nothing hapens:

```
[root@server ~]# /etc/init.d/mysql start
-bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory

[root@server ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
-bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
```

So, I tried this method:

```
[root@server ~]# service mysql start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysql.service
```

It's been stuck on that message and nothing is happening. I've checked *ps aux | grep mysql* and I don't see the service running:

```
[root@server ~]# ps aux | grep mysql
root     10688  0.0  0.1 115212   644 ?        Ss   20:08   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post
root     12646  0.0  0.2 132520  1396 pts/0    S+   20:16   0:00 /bin/systemctl start mysql.service
root     12852  0.0  0.1 112640   960 pts/1    S+   20:17   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Any ideas?

Comment: After a while, I got this message: `Job for mysqld.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysqld.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`

Comment: Is SELinux running in enforcing mode?  `/usr/sbin/getenforce`.  If it is, set it to `Permissive` mode and try starting MySQL again -- `/usr/sbin/setenforce 0`  If that allows you to start it, you then need to track down what prevented it from starting in the first place before reenabling SELinux.

Comment: I notice that you have the pid file in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid` which I believe is not the standard location (`/var/run/mysql/mysql.pid/`). That alone would almost certainly cause problems with SELinux (I know from experience)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski SELinux is not enabled: `[root@server ~]# /usr/sbin/getenforce
Disabled`

Comment: Check your logs then.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I started mysql like this: `systemctl start  mysql.service` and I got this error now: `Job for mysqld.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysqld.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.` So, I ran the said command and found these: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=b7EB0xKg. I am not sure about all these errors. I might give MariaDB a go.

Comment: The relevant thing there is `2015-08-09 20:39:38 4435 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.`.  Run `/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade`. It may need a user/pass via `-u user -p`. I can't remember.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 5.6 will not start on a 512M VM without swap.  The error is most likely an out of memory condition.  You have the choice of:

1. Install MySQL 5.7 (currently RC2).  The repos that you are using have this available [as an option](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/12/11/installing-mysql-5-7-dmr3-with-the-official-yum-repos.html).  5.7 in it's default config actually uses less RAM.
2. Modify the configuration of your 5.6 server to use less RAM.  I have an example [available here](http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html).
3. Enable swap.

Comment: You help me a lot. I share your solution at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=781036&#781036

Comment: @Morgan Tocker the links you've left above are broken currently.

Answer (score 3):

For CentOS 7, mysql is transitioning to mariadb. Under /usr/lib/systemd/system should find mariadb.service file.  Then simply run

> sudo systemctl start mariadb.service

Then when you run /usr/bin/mysql  , it works!

Comment: This worked for me (In my case I installed mysql from webmin and I when I checked yum history the command was: yum  -y install mariadb maria). Thank you.

Comment: This answer works fine for me, many thanks @joseph-camaioni

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable swap memory. Try this.

With CentOS 7 Enable swap memory ram

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=4096 bs=1MiB
$ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
$ sudo mkswap /swapfile
$ sudo swapon /swapfile
$ swapon -s
```